# dup and dup2 commands

Tags: c, operating-system, dup2, dup

What I'm trying to do is that put the output  of the ls command in a file, and then use grep command to read from that file and store it in a new file and based on the contents on that file, print something on the terminal.

So the following output redirections are there:

1) from standard output to file known as oioioi.txt (for ls command) 
2) from oioioi.txt to grep.txt (for grep command) 
3) from grep.txt back to terminal

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
        //if(!fork())
                //execl("/bin/grep","grep","input","oioioi.txt",0);
        FILE *fp1,*fp2;
        int fd,fd2;
        fp1=fopen("oioioi.txt","w+");
        fp2=fopen("grep.txt","w+");
        fd=fileno(fp1);
        fd2=fileno(fp2);
        char filename[40],id[40],marks[40],filename2[40];
        scanf("%s %s %s",filename,id,marks);
        char *execarg2[]={"ls",0};
        dup2(fd,1); //1st redirection
        //close(1);
        if(!fork())
        {
                execv("/bin/ls",execarg2);
        }
        sleep(1);
        wait(NULL);
        //dup(fd2);
        close(fd);
        dup(1);
        dup2(fd2,1); //2nd redirection
        if(!fork())
        {
                //sleep(1);
                execl("/bin/grep","grep",filename,"oioioi.txt",0);
        }
        sleep(1);
        wait(NULL);
        close(fd2);
        dup2(1,fd2); //3rd one which is the incorrect one
        fscanf(fp2,"%s",filename2);
                printf("%s",filename2);
        if(strcmp(filename2,filename)==0)
                printf("FILE FOUND");

        return(0);
}
```

I believe that the 3rd one is incorrect. However I'm not really sure of the first 2 either. If you guys could have a look at my code and tell me where I'm going wrong or give me an exampple using dup for the following redirections, i'd really really be grateful

Comment: It would help if your variable names were (1) symmetric (i.e. fd1=fileno(fp1); fd2 = fileno(fp2); and (2) give more meaningful names to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem begins at your first dup call: `dup(fd, 1);`. In that line, you lose your standard output to the terminal. If you wanted to secretly keep a reference to it, you'd `dup(STDOUT_FILENO);` beforehand.

It follows that subsequent calls to `printf` will actually be redirected to `fd2` and not to `stdout`'s original fd (1).

There are probably some other issues lurking here, but that's as far as I was able to grok it (see my comments on the question).

n.b.

The manpage of `dup2` states that it closes the new fd (second arg) if necessary, making the `close` in

```
close(fd2);
dup(1, fd2);
```

redundant.

Comment: Closing the target fd before `dup2` is not only redundant, but it introduces a race condition in multithreaded code.